# preg_replace pattern instead of recursive function for <span style=

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have something like this:

> `$text = 'Getting the right kitchen appliances and home appliances for your situation is important to us.We want to make sure you are served to the best of our ability.  Please feel free to contact us at any time with any inquiries you may have: <h3 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #0000ff;"><span style="color: #3366ff;"><span style="color: #0000ff;"><span style="color: #000000;"><strong> </strong>General inquiries (**please include your location**):  </span></span></span></span>';`

and `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace(
    '/<span style="color(.+?)">(.+?)<\/span>/s', 
    "<span>$2</span>", 
    $text
);
```

That replaces only first occurrence. How to change that to replace every occurrences of this pattern?

Comment: I need this for that particular case. Only that span's with color need to be replaced so it won't break.

Comment: have you tried flag `m`

Comment: What would be the expected output in this case, @Conrad?

Comment: @Dwza: Not sure how that would help. The `m` modifier has no effect if the pattern doesn't contain line anchors, i.e. `^` or `$`. [Relevant docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: @AmalMurali I expect to remove all color stylings from the text:
<span> ...</span> instead of <span style="color: ..."> ... </span> for each span

Comment: @Conrad: Then why do you care about what's inside the `<span>`? Just do `echo preg_replace('/<span style="color(.+?)">/', "<span>", $text);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this

```
$text = 'Getting the right kitchen appliances and home appliances
 for your situation is important to us.We want to make sure you are
 served to the best of our ability. Please feel free to contact us 
at any time with any inquiries you may have: <h3 style="text-align: left;">
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><span style="color: #3366ff;">
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><span style="color: #000000;"><strong>
 </strong>General inquiries (**please include your location**): 
</span></span></span></span>';

$text = preg_replace("/<span[^>]+\>/i", '<span style="\$2">\$3</span>', $text);
```

Output:

```
Getting the right kitchen appliances and home appliances for your situation is important to us.We want to make sure you are served to the best of our ability. Please feel free to contact us at any time with any inquiries you may have: <h3 style="text-align: left;"><span style="$2">$3</span><span style="$2">$3</span><span style="$2">$3</span><span style="$2">$3</span><strong> </strong>General inquiries (**please include your location**): </span></span></span></span>
```

Comment: sort of, but how to avoid what was mentioned before, to left styles other than color ?

like that? 
preg_replace('/<span style="color(.+?);(.*?)">(.+?)<\/span>/s', '<span style="$2">$3</span>', $text)

Answer (score 0):

i think you just want to skip color attribute from text, so why don't you just use color in preg_replace instead of complete span.
try this:

```
preg_replace(
        '/color(.+?);/s', 
         "",  
        $text);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.